# How to define a new arithmetic operation in Python

Tags: python

How to define a new arithmetic operation in python

Suppose I want to have operator `?` such that `A?B` will result in `A` to power of `1/B`

So the statement below would be true

`A?B == A**(1/B)`

for instance in R I can achieve it as following

```
`?` <- function(A,B) A^(1/B)

4?2
#2
```

Comment: `~` sign is already taken in python: it's bitwise NOT operator, you shouldn't override it

Answer (score 3):

You can’t.

The set of available operators in Python, with their precedence and associativity, is given by the [language spec](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#operators) and can not be changed. Within those bounds, you can define their behaviour for your own classes, by implementing the appropriate “[dunder](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#special-method-names)” methods, but you cannot escape `~` being a unary operator.

Answer (score 1):

Python has pre-defined operators, including `~`.
Though you cannot define new operators, you can overload them for your types, so you can define a class with one integer property and overload for the `^` (or any other one in [this table](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/operator-overloading-in-python/)):

```
class MyNumber:
    def __init__(self, x):
       self.x = x

    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self.x ** (1/other.x)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = MyNumber(5)
    b = MyNumber(3)
    print(a^b)
```